# Multi lingual text with Japanese characters on XeTeX

Tags: xetex, cjk, xecjk, japanese

I need to be able to use different languages and their fonts for a paper. There is no need for multi lingual headings and all of that stuff. Just some examples in my text like so:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=endperiod]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={* Caps}]{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
\newfontfamily\russianfont{Liberation Serif}
\newfontfamily\ipafont{Doulos SIL}
\newfontfamily\churchslavonicfont{PonomarUnicode}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{Liberation Serif}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage[oldxetex]{zxjatype}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\newfontfamily\japanesefont{zxjafont}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{churchslavonic}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguages{russian,romanian,churchslavonic,greek,japanese}
\usepackage{yfonts}

\newcommand{\ipa}[1]{{\ipafont {#1}}}
\newcommand{\aks}[1]{{\churchslavonicfont {#1}}}
\newcommand{\rus}[1]{{\russianfont {#1}}}
\newcommand{\gre}[1]{{\greekfont {#1}}}
\newcommand{\jpn}[1]{{\japanesefont {#1}}}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\cfoot{}
\ofoot{\pagemark\hspace{-.5cm}}

\begin{document}
As you can see just some text with some fancy characters that I'd like to enter like this: /\ipa{waʊ̯}/ or \aks{ши} or \jpn{かわいい}.
\end{document}
```

Everything is working with the exception of Japanese. From what I've found till now the zxjatype-package seems promising but it just won't run even though I have copied the .sty-file to the correct directory. But of course I'd be happy to use whatever works!